# Can you remove a file from google drive by transferring it to your PC without deleting it?

Tags: google-drive

Is there anyway to remove a file from google drive by transferring it to your pc without deleting it? I dont want my files to be on google drive anymore but if it delete them there, I know the files will still be there in Google's cloud.

Comment: Make a copy of the file in a new location.  Delete the original and synchronize the change

Comment: Yea but the file will still be in google's cloud when I delete the original.

Comment: I move files through Google all the time.  I sincerly doubt Google is keeping a cloud backup of all the picture's, etc.  Moving by definition copies the file and deletes the original. Sneaker-Net!

Comment: @navodithshankar - If you delete the original in the folder that is being synchronized then the file being deleted will be synchronized.  You can also log into Google Drive in a browser and delete the file.  If you didn’t want the file in the cloud why did you upload it?